# Convert Single XElement to Json array using c#

Tags: c#, xml, json

```
JsonConvert.SerializeXNode("<Root><Student key="Student1" value="4" /> <Student key="Student2" value="0" /></Root>")
```

it's return

```
{"Root":{Student:[{key:Student1,value=4}},Student:{key:Student2,value=0}]}
```

but i need

```
JsonConvert.SerializeXNode("<Root><Student key="Student1" value="4" /></Root>")
```

from

```
{"Root":[{Student:{key:Student1,value=4}}]}
```

but it's return

```
{"Root":{Student:{key:Student1,value=4}}}
```

Any one can help to this

Comment: I think your first return is wrong.. I get `{"Root":{"Student":[{"@key":"Student1","@value":"4"},{"@key":"Student2","@value":"0"}]}}`, with an array of `Student`. It's even logical, in JSON you can't have two `Student` properties that have the same name!

Comment: but it's return json values.where was problem mean.it's retrun object when single element else it's return array list

Answer (score 0):

You could detect if there's a single `Student` element and if so, add an one after it with all attributes removed. Then, you would serialize it into JSON and perform a simple `String.Replace()` in order to remove the `null` entry:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var singleElement = false;
        var x = XDocument
            .Parse(@"<Root><Student key=""Student1"" value=""4""/></Root>");
        if (x.Root.Elements().Count() == 1)
        {
            singleElement = true;
            var single = x.Root.Elements().First();
            x.Root.Elements().First().AddAfterSelf(single);
            x.Root.Elements().Last().Attributes().ToList()
                .ForEach(a => a.Remove());
            //optionally, remove the value, if you expect one
            x.Root.Elements().Last().Value = String.Empty;
        }
        var xml = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(x);
        if (singleElement)
            xml = xml.Replace(",null", "");
    }
}
```